# how to redirect to current page in joomla1.5 after login

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm working in joomla 1.5 site. When sign in, I want to redirect to current page. No need to go to index page. I'm using redirecttofirstlogin plugin to redirect to desired page. It works perfectly. But i want to pass the current page url to that link. How to take even the current url.

This will return wrong url: `JURI::getInstance()->toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line to get current URL in Joomla

```
$current_url = JURI::getInstance();
```

After that you have to pass `$current_url` variable to desired link as per your functionality.

---

For Concatenate the URL, you have use this syntax,

```
$base_url = JURI::BASE();
```

For Concatenate :

`$full_url = $base_url."index.php?option=com_properties&view=property&id=19&Itemid=54";`.

Comment: For example, i need "$base_url"+/index.php?option=com_properties&view=property&id=19&Itemid=54. For this, using getInstance(), i can get only "$base_url"+/index.php?option=com_properties&view=property&Itemid=54... It leaves id=2.

Answer (score 0):

Try `JURI::current()` it will give you the current url.

Update for joomla 1.5:-

```
$u =& JURI::getInstance( );
echo 'URI is ' . $u->toString();
```

For more info you can check here- http://docs.joomla.org/JURI

Comment: Sorry irfan. This wil return only base url. such that mywebsite.com/index.php. But i need full url.

Comment: @BharathRam:Yes it's not working in joomla1.5.But working in joomla2.5.My mistake I did not tested it for 1.5.Check my update answer may this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to redirect to the current page after logging in, then it can be done without any code.

In the Joomla Backend, go to the Module Manager and open the Login module. There is a parameter called **"Login Redirection Page"** which all you have to do is set to **"Select Item"**, so it's basically unselected.

I have just tested this myself and it works